# Recurring contribution report by LineItem financial type

Tags: recurring-contributions

I am looking for a report that lists recurring contributions by Line item financial type. I have tried the Find Contribution report, the Advanced Search, the contribution report Recurring Contributions... They all only query the Contribution table Financial Type. I need to query the Line Item financial type.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Extended report extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) does provide Line item financial type filtering but not sure if they filter only recurring contribution. There are of Contribution reports with additional filter/fields available that are not present in core reports. You may need to add filter to show only recurring contribution using [hook_civicrm_alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/) hook.

(Even Bookkeeping Transactions Report does filter financial type using line item FT.)

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a standard report that shows the line item financial type, but I might be mistaken.
You can query the table `civicrm_line_item` if you have some kind of BI tool?